# Use field value in limit_choices_to in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-mptt

I have two models `Project` and `Group`. My groups belong to a specific project. My groups have the fields `project = ForeignKey(Project)` and `parent = ForeignKey('self')`.

Can I use `limit_choices_to` to make sure the options in foreign key `parent` only consist of groups inside the same project?

I'm thinking of something like

```
def limit_choices_to(self):
    return {'project': self.project}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is impossible to do at the model level but you can change the queryset for this field in the form's constructor.

```
class GroupForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(GroupForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.instance.project:
            self.fields['parent'].queryset = Group.objects.filter(
                                                project=self.instance.project)
```

**UPDATE**: To do it in the admin you have to set the [`form`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.form) attribute of the `ModelAdmin`:

```
class GroupAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = GroupForm
```

Comment: Thank you! But how can I accomplish the same result in the admin section?

Comment: I think, this should be possible to do on model level with
`limit_choices_to={'project__id': Value('id')}`
but I am getting errors like 
`psycopg2.errors.InvalidCursorName: cursor "_django_curs_140361007625984_sync_1" does not exist`

Answer (score 1):

For the admin section I found hacky way to do it. My example is with admin.StackedInline, but almost sure it will work with plain ModelAdmin. I left it here just in case someone likes this solution:

```
class ProfessionalInline(admin.StackedInline):
model = Professional

fieldsets = [
    ('Research information', {
        'fields': ('team', 'projects')
    }),
    ('Profile information', {
        'fields': ('age', 'gender', 'receive_emails')
    })]

def get_parent_object_from_request(self, request):
    """
    Returns the parent object from the request or None.

    Note that this only works for Inlines, because the `parent_model`
    is not available in the regular admin.ModelAdmin as an attribute.
    """
    resolved = resolve(request.path_info)
    if resolved.kwargs:
        return self.parent_model.objects.get(pk=resolved.kwargs['object_id'])
    return None

def formfield_for_manytomany(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
    '''Extremely hacky'''
    account = self.get_parent_object_from_request(request)
    if db_field.name == 'projects':
        kwargs['queryset'] = Project.objects.filter(team=account.professional.team)
    return super().formfield_for_manytomany(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

For the admin you can override `get_form()` from `admin.ModelAdmin` if you don't want to make separate for. This is working for me with Django 3.2:

```py
    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, change=False, **kwargs):
        form = super().get_form(request, obj, change, **kwargs)
        queryset = form.base_fields["<field>"].queryset
        form.base_fields["<field>"].queryset = queryset.filter(...)
        return form
```